# Does cornstarch affect the pH of what I'm cooking?

Tags: canning, acidity, cornstarch

I'm considering canning some fruit compotes to use with yogurt, and the recipe I want to use (which was not designed with canning in mind, found here: http://www.simplebites.net/how-to-make-your-own-fruit-bottom-yogurt/ ) calls for cornstarch to be used to thicken everything up.

Now, I do not have a pressure cooker, so I would be doing this with a water bath canner, and I'd like to know if the cornstarch is going to lower the acidity of the fruit mixture, or if I should use some other thickening agent or method.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about the pH, but cornstarch can make your compote separate when canned: http://www.sbcanning.com/2011/08/canning-pie-filling-education-in-clear.html.  Tapioca or clearjel is a recommended alternative thickener.

Comment: Oh cornstarch, shame on you! Thanks for warning me about this! Do you think Pectin would also be an acceptable alternative? I know it's generally used more in jams and such, but it seems like it'd be a bit easier to get than cleargel.

Comment: Never mind, after reading up on the differences between the two, it looks like cleargel will be my solution. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome!  I use clearjel for thickening when I'm canning.  It's easy to use and comes out great.  Natural pectin's lovely if what you're using has it--apples, say, or quince.

Comment: @Fisher- You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any info on the affect of pH, but cornstarch can make your compote separate when canned: http://www.sbcanning.com/2011/08/canning-pie-filling-education-in-clear.html.

Two alternative thickeners are tapioca and clearjel.  I've used clearjel for canning with excellent results.  I haven't used tapioca to can, but do prefer it in my pies.

(posted as an answer per Sobachatina's recommendation)